# Why is Ewald summation faster than normal summation?

Tags: field-theory, computational-physics, molecular-dynamics

I posted this on the Mathematics SE, but wasn't sure if it was purely a mathematical problem. If I should take this down because of cross-posting rules, I will do so gladly.

I have been trying to understand Ewald summation, and I understand the procedure... but don't understand why it's better. I am following [this document](http://micro.stanford.edu/mediawiki/images/4/46/Ewald_notes.pdf).

Equation 3 from the above document says that the sum over all pairs to evaluate energy of a system with Periodic Boundary Conditions is
$$E = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \sum _{\mathbf{n}} \sum _{i=1}^N \sum _{j=1} ^{N} \frac{q_i q_j}{|\mathbf{r}_{ij}+\mathbf{n}L|}$$

Where $\mathbf{n}L$ is a term used to consider other images in our system, apart from our primary cell.

After doing all the Fourier transforms and writing interactions as short- and long-range interactions, we come down to the final equation which looks like:
$$E = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \sum _{\mathbf{n}} \sum _{i=1}^N \sum _{j=1} ^{N} \frac{q_i q_j}{|\mathbf{r}_{ij}+\mathbf{n}L|} \mathrm{erfc} \left(\frac{\mathbf{r}_i -\mathbf{r}_j + \mathbf{n}L}{\sqrt{2}\sigma} \right) + \frac{1}{2V\epsilon _0}\sum_{\mathbf{k}\neq \mathbf{0}}\frac{e^{-\sigma^2 k^2/2}}{k^2}|S(\mathbf{k})|^2 -\\ \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\sum_{i=1}^{N}q_i ^2$$
where $$S(\mathbf{k}) = \sum_{i=1}^N q_i e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{r}_i}$$
My question is, why is the lower summation better, $O(N^{3/2})$ and better than the upper summation? Both summations look pretty terrible, and I almost want to say $O(N^2)$.

What am I missing? Any advice you have would be appreciated!

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4015301/11127

Comment: Does this help? [Symmetry in program for ewald summation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/205794/37364)